# ARCHS, missing archive intermediate build files and failure to deploy onto real device

Tags: swift, arm, arm64, arm7

My project runs and compiles fine on simulator - but stubbornly won't on my real device. The errors are below.

Indeed the archive intermediate file 'FoodFeed' is missing from the derived data folder - but I don't think I can simply 'put it back' - because it is meant to be created during the build folder.

I've tried toggling lots of settings on the build architecture - but fundamentally I don't really understand the syntax or the distinction between the different modes. I have SwiftyGif and SoftUIView installed via SPM - and I wondered if one of those is somehow clashing with the architecture on my phone (I can get other projects to launch on my phone) - but removing the packages and doing a clean recompile does not fix the problem.

One other issue is that my development account was recently changed - so I have also wondered if the old details were hardcoded somewhere deep in the set up - since this is only happening when I deploy to a real device.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the excluded architectures fixed it.